# Using Sockets to transfer Data with MonoDroid

Tags: c#, android, sockets, mono, xamarin.android

I'm trying to send some information to a server with Android using Monodroid.

The code is as follows:

```
public void sendSomething()
    {
        sock = new TcpClient();
        sock.Connect(Dns.GetHostAddresses("a.domain.com"), 7777);

        String d;
        d = "somedata";

        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(sock.GetStream());
        // StreamReader r = new StreamReader(sock.GetStream());

        w.WriteLine(d);
        w.Flush();

        sock.Close();
     }
```

It works fine if I run the exact same routine in a winforms application, but when linked to a button click in monodroid (running on the android virtual device - I'm using the evaluation version) the server will see the connection but no data is received.

Does anybody have any idea why this could be?

(edited to ammend code)

Comment: Do other client applications work from the virtual device. E.g. Can you access a basic web page from the browser? Receive email etc.?

Comment: Hi, yes I can access web pages with the device's built in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a server issue. E.g. let's assume that:

a) your winform app running on Windows / MS.NET (and not on Mono / Linux or OSX);

b) your server is Windows-based too and does a `ReadLine` to read sockets

Then the `NewLine` between the write (Unix `\n`) and the read (Windows `\r\n\`) could explain why the server does not report what's being read.

Can you show us how you're reading the data on the server ? (edit your question)

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem!
I Changed:
 d = "somedata"; 
to 
 d = "somedata\r\n"; 

and it's now working my day long headache is starting to clear! :)

Comment: Glad it did :-) You can also set the `NewLine` property (that `StreamWriter` gets from `TextWriter`) to match the Windows new lines (or change the `StreamReader` in your server application). As long as both are identical you should be fine.